# "No route to host" (HY000/2002) mysqli error on a remote server every now and then - what can I do besides contacting the host?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Every now and then, I get following error: `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No route to host in` *(path to my mysqli_connect)*. My site is on a remote server owned by my webhost, so the problem might be on their side, but before accusing them of causing such an error, I want to make sure it's not my fault. In fact, I expect it to be my fault, from several reasons:

- the hosting company is one of the most popular in my country, and still Google search of HY000/2002 and its name found nothing relevant. Seems others don't have this problem with them.
- I first encountered this problem after previous major change of my code (php, mysql, few javascript snippets). It could be just a coincidence, but more probably it is not.
- if it was a server fault, I would expect the connection to crash and remain dead for some time. However, after each such error I can just reload the page and the problem is over... for few more reloads.

**The pattern I have found yet is that there is some (~1%) chance of triggering the bug while running mysqli_connect.** Each function working with database has its own include of the `db.php` file (where the database is initialized), so parts of code where lots of nested database-calling functions are called are quite dangerous (up to about 10% that the reload will lead to a crash), while those where all the queries are done without function calls are "safe".

I can think of few workarounds minimizing the probability of the crash, but they wouldn't solve the main problem: that mysqli_connect fails sometimes and I have no idea why, or what does trigger it.

What I have changed before I first encountered this problem:

- I turned most of my mysqli queries into prepared statements. Few functions were versatile - if I wanted to feed them with parametrizable arguments instead of custom SQL code chunk, I would have to split them into 10+ other functions. I know keeping non-parametrized queries is a bad practice, but I made sure I sanitized every content that might get to the function, so changing them to 100% safe parametrized queries seems like a small priority task. Unless it causes the problems somehow - I thought so for some time, because my "mysqli_query" functions tend to be called in the most "dangerous" parts of my site.
- upgrade from static to JavaScript Google Maps API
- some changes to the tables in my database, but not to the database itself
- cleaning .htaccess file (previously I have forbidden caching for testing reasons - no reason for this on live site)

Here is my `db.php` file - the same as it was before the problems started (the password is not real):

```
<?php
  $spojeni=mysqli_connect('mysql01','pavel','mypasswd');
  if (!$spojeni) die('Nepodařilo se připojit k databázi.');
  mysqli_query($spojeni, "USE ehistory");
  mysqli_set_charset($spojeni,'utf8');
  mysqli_query($spojeni, "SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_czech_ci';");
?>
```

I can't post whole site (or even all queries) here, so comment and ask if you think some part of my code should be important; in such a case, add explanation why it might matter.

EDIT: I asked my webhost and received the IP address that should be substituted for "mysql01". I replaced "mysqli01" with the IP address and nothing changed. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

> My site is on a remote server owned by my webhost, so the problem
>   might be on their side, but before accusing them of causing such an
>   error, I want to make sure it's not my fault. In fact, I expect it to
>   be my fault, from several reasons:

mysql01 is not a Fully qualified domain name (FQDN) Please use the IP or ask your web hosting for the corrected FQDN.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. However, it didn't help in the end - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an IP routing problem (network layer 3). I believe the only thing to be checked on your side is whether the correct MySQL server IP/hostname is supplied to *mysqli_connect()* **every time**. To eliminate eventual resolver problems try to use a plain IP instead of hostname.

Comment: The two things, I can thing of it, are long queries (you always get the error in the same page?) and the other possible issue could be at bad switch that is dropping packages. In this case, other customers should be affected too. Definitely, you are dealing with mysql timeout issue. You can always test your code in another hosting (there are some cheap hosting for $1 or $2) that you can use for testing.

Comment: Sorry that I can not help you more :(  I run out of ideas.

Comment: Testing on localhost can even be cheaper and faster. :-)

Comment: Our codes, most of times, works on localhost, since it is a dedicated server and usually our local computers have more dedicated resources than the servers that we can afford with a hosting provider. But testing it on another shared environment, it will mimic the same variables (or similar) and you make sure that your code/mysql performance are ok or not. And for a couple bucks you can test your code.